# Evaluating $-3(5-7)^2$: multiply by $-3$ or square it first?

Tags: arithmetic

As stupid as this is, I don't know.
$$-3(5-7)^2$$
Multiply by $-3$ or square it first?

Comment: The exponent should be handled first, but this is again another example of sloppy notation that no self-respecting mathematician would use.

Comment: Here... some extra parentheses for ya... $-3(5-7)^2 = (-3)\cdot ((5-7)^2)$.  You have $-3(5-7)^2 = -3(-2)^2 = (-3)\cdot 4 = -12$

Comment: You can see [here](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/132.1.00w/w6.pdf) one of the greatest mathematicians of our time using that notation. You can judge yourself if the claim from a random nobody on the Internet that it is sloppy is true or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the mnenomic PEMDAS (Please Excuse My Dear Aunt Sally) for order of operations: 
 *P*arentheses, *E*xponents, *M*ultiplication, *D*ivision, *A*ddition, and *S*ubtraction.

In your case, take care of items inside the parenthesis first ($5-7 = -2$), then square  ($-2^2 = 4$) and finally multiply ($-3 \cdot 4 = -12$).